# How to keep the first parameter value only?

Tags: perl, catalyst

In my Perl Catalyst application, I get the value of a URL parameter like this, typically:

```
my $val = $c->request->params->{arg} || '';
```

But the URL could contain multiple `arg=$Val`. I only want to keep the first value of `arg=`. I could add this throughout my code:

```
my $val = $c->request->params->{arg} || '';
$val = $val->[0] if (ref($val) eq 'ARRAY');
```

That is rather ugly. Is there a way to pick up the first value or a url parameter in a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Does your app actually expect multiple values for parameter `arg`? If not, all you need is

```
my $val = $c->request->params->{arg} || '';
```

Sure, it will be garbage if the user provides you with a garbage url, but there's nothing you can do to prevent the user from giving you garbage.

If it's actually valid to have more than one value for parameter `arg`, why would you want just the first value? You'd actually want all the values.

```
sub param_vals {
   my ($params, $name) = @_;
   return () if !exists($params->{name});
   return $params->{$name} if !ref($params->{name});
   return @{ $params->{$name} };
}

my @args = param_vals($c->request->{params}, 'arg');
```

Comment: I expect one arg=$val, having more than one is a mistake from the client.

Comment: I control the server, not the clients!

Comment: I know. What I said wouldn't make sense otherwise. (The "you" in my last comment meant "a user".)

Comment: Let's use an example. There's no reason to treat `arg=good&arg=gargbage` differently than `arg=gargbage`, so `my $val = $c->request->params->{arg} || '';` is all your need.

Answer (score 0):

I just read the code to `Catalyst::Request` but I don't see anything to always pull out a single value. Too bad Cat doesn't use something like `Hash::MultiValue`!